# Issue occurs while installing the windows service on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have created a windows service which is successfully installed on my machine as well as some other local machines.

But when I try to install the same on client's server which is **Windows Server 2012 R2** it is getting error stack as below:

```
The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

[image: The inner exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was thrown with the following error message: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.]

For this, I have tried some solution as below:

1. Adding **ServicePipeTimeout** in **`regedit`** so that it can increase the timeout.
2. Comparing Microsoft .Net Framework's version used in **windows service** and Windows Server 2012 R2.

Both of the solutions did not work for me. Can someone guide me through this issue?

Comment: In your `ServiceInstaller` class which `StartType` have you selected (Boot, System, Automatic, Manual, Disabled)?

Comment: @Andrea: its Automatic

Comment: Ok, try setting it to Manual (you can change it later under "Services"). The service installation should now complete. You will still have the problem when you (manually) start your service, but you should be able to troubleshoot the problem by remote debugging or looking at the event viewer.

Comment: Okay, will try that soon as client's server is not available right now.